# Dependency not resolved while creating OSGI bundle having selenium web driver

Tags: selenium, dependencies, osgi, bundle, pom.xml

I am trying to create an OSGI bundle having selenium firefox web driver. I used the same dependency in maven project and it all worked fine. But when i am creating bundle, compilation  gives no issues. But on installing bundle, there are some internal dependencies which can not be resolved. There is a property in maven bundle plugin 
embed-transitivy. I set it to true which solves almost all the internal dependencies of firefox-webdriver. Still some could not be resolved.

Error:

```
net.sf.cglib.asm.util -- Cannot be resolved
org.apache.avalon.framework.logger -- Cannot be resolved
org.apache.log -- Cannot be resolved
org.apache.log4j from log4j.over.slf4j (4)
org.apache.tools.ant -- Cannot be resolved
org.apache.tools.ant.types -- Cannot be resolved
org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.hook -- Cannot be resolved
sun.misc -- Cannot be resolved
```

Moreover, when I am searching for net.sf.cglib.asm.util in cglib-nodep.2.1_3.jar there is no such class. Internally firefox-driver using cglib-nodep.2.1_3.jar. I guess there is some problem with the version 2.1_3. I dont know How OSGI resolves this version name.

Can somebody please figure out what could be an issue. and where do I find the class net.sf.cglib.asm.util ?

PS: I am using 2.25.0 version of firefox-driver which internally depends upon cglib and fetches 2.1_3 version of it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a different problem all together I think. You might like to have a look at this.
http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/detail?id=208

There is the same problem you have faced. So read that. It might help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are facing the problem described here http://spring.io/blog/2009/01/19/exposing-the-boot-classpath-in-osgi/ and here http://blog.meschberger.ch/2008/10/osgi-bundles-require-classes-from.html